# Craft Setup 3.6.5.1 with MYSQL with SSL version 5.7.29

Tags: craft3, mysql, ssl

I'm trying to install Craft version 3.6.5.1 with MYSQL version 5.7.29 from Azure.
While setup it fails with the following error

Testing database credentials ... failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [9002] SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got this sorted using Craft's database [attributes](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/db-settings.html#attributes) config setting.

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7583#issuecomment-781168257